# Recvfrom() keeps returning wrong value

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp

I call udpclient in main where i pass "this is a test" as the parameter message.

```
#define MAX_BUFFER 128


void udpclient(char *message, char *target_ip, int target_port){

///* address of server we trying to reach */
struct sockaddr_in targetaddress;
/* buffer to receive echo */
char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];

/* create socket */
int socketfd;
socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if(socketfd == -1)
    socketerror();

/* target server informations */
memset(&targetaddress, 0, sizeof(targetaddress));
targetaddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
targetaddress.sin_port   = htons(target_port);
targetaddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(target_ip);
```

After i send message to server, the server must reply "echo: this is a test", but recvfrom() for some reason is returning n = 8, so when i do write(1, buffer, n) it truncates buffer.

```
/* send message to targetaddress */
ssize_t n;
n = sendto(socketfd, message, sizeof(message), 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &targetaddress, sizeof(targetaddress));
if(n == -1)
    udpsenderror();

printf("%i\n", n);

socklen_t addrlen;
addrlen = sizeof(targetaddress);
/* receive echo from targetaddress */
n = recvfrom(socketfd, buffer, MAX_BUFFER, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &targetaddress, &addrlen);
if(n == -1)
    udpechoerror();

printf("%i\n", n);
write(1, "echo: ", 6);
write(1, buffer, n);

return;
```

}

Recvfrom() should be returning the lenght of message if i'm not mistaken, I don't know where i'm doing wrong! Help!?

Comment: From the [`recvfrom` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) *The receive calls normally return any data available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested.*.

Comment: Given `char *message`, just what do you think `sizeof(message)` returns?

Comment: Andrew Henle i think there is where the error is! Going to confirm it

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it!! Stay safe, stay home

Answer (score 1):

```
n = sendto(socketfd, message, sizeof(message), 0, (const struct sockaddr *) &targetaddress, sizeof(targetaddress));
```

Since `message` is a `char *`, `sizeof(message)` gives the number of bytes a `char *` takes on your platform. Apparently, that's 8 bytes, so you sent an 8-byte message.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thank you for the explanation
Stay safe